# Ruby ActiveSupport 1.week VS 7.days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

My question is really short :
Why 1.week take more time than 7.days ?

```
        user     system      total        real
1.week: 10.848330   0.117741  10.966071 ( 11.623818)
7.days:  6.427236   0.059907   6.487143 (  6.869768)
```

I've seen it (from : [github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b2eb1d1c55a59fee1e6c4cba7030d8ceb524267c/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb)):

```
  def weeks
    ActiveSupport::Duration.weeks(self)
  end
  alias :week :weeks
```

```
  def days
    ActiveSupport::Duration.days(self)
  end
  alias :day :days
```

And this (from : [github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb))

```
    SECONDS_PER_MINUTE = 60
    SECONDS_PER_HOUR   = 3600
    SECONDS_PER_DAY    = 86400
    SECONDS_PER_WEEK   = 604800
    SECONDS_PER_MONTH  = 2629746  # 1/12 of a gregorian year
    SECONDS_PER_YEAR   = 31556952 # length of a gregorian year (365.2425 days)

    PARTS_IN_SECONDS = {
      seconds: 1,
      minutes: SECONDS_PER_MINUTE,
      hours:   SECONDS_PER_HOUR,
      days:    SECONDS_PER_DAY,
      weeks:   SECONDS_PER_WEEK,
      months:  SECONDS_PER_MONTH,
      years:   SECONDS_PER_YEAR
    }.freeze

    PARTS = [:years, :months, :weeks, :days, :hours, :minutes, :seconds].freeze
```

```
      def weeks(value) #:nodoc:
        new(value * SECONDS_PER_WEEK, weeks: value)
      end
```

```
      def days(value) #:nodoc:
        new(value * SECONDS_PER_DAY, days: value)
      end
```

But, for me, it's just a multiplication, it shall not take more time !
And, worse, if I do `7 * 24.hours`, it's faster !

```
7 * 24.hours:  4.635190   0.058839   4.694029 (  5.049936)
```

Thanks for your explanation !

Comment: When sharing a benchmark, you should *always* try to also show exactly how you generated it.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that your benchmarking methodology and/or your statistical methods are flawed in some way. I always recommend that anybody thinking about writing a benchmark should read the *entire thread* at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mechanical-sympathy/m4opvy4xq3U/7lY8x8SvHgwJ and only start writing the benchmark, when you understand every word of every message in that thread. Taking a couple of classes in statistics usually also doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you are testing here (since you haven't shown your actual benchmark script) but since both code-paths are very similar, they do in fact also show very similar performance characteristics.

Using the [benchmark-ips gem](https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips) (with Ruby 2.7.1 and ActiveSupport 6.0.3), I can confirm that they are both about equally fast:

```
require 'benchmark/ips'
require 'active_support/core_ext'

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report("1.week") { 1.week }
  x.report("7.days") { 7.days }

  x.compare!
end
```

On my machine, I get the following result:

```
Warming up --------------------------------------
              1.week   195.777k i/100ms
              7.days   197.404k i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
              1.week      1.915M (± 2.5%) i/s -      9.593M in   5.011463s
              7.days      1.855M (± 5.1%) i/s -      9.278M in   5.015019s

Comparison:
              1.week:  1915476.4 i/s
              7.days:  1855425.8 i/s - same-ish: difference falls within error
```

Comment: Yep, it would appear from the question that the test was run once and therefore did not take into account warm-up time.